# packet loss and unable to ssh

Tags: linux, networking, ssh, ping

I am trying to connect to a linux server from my linux machine using SSH over LAN. I don't know what the problem is but sometimes I can ping the server but can not ssh whereas at other times I am neither able to ping nor ssh. While pinging, I found that there is some packet loss as shown below.

ashutosh@ashutosh-ThinkCentre:~$ ping 172.16.5.116

PING 172.16.5.116 (172.16.5.116) 56(84) bytes of data.

64 bytes from 172.16.5.116: icmp_req=4 ttl=63 time=0.458 ms

64 bytes from 172.16.5.116: icmp_req=21 ttl=63 time=0.272 ms

64 bytes from 172.16.5.116: icmp_req=22 ttl=63 time=0.275 ms

64 bytes from 172.16.5.116: icmp_req=30 ttl=63 time=0.275 ms

64 bytes from 172.16.5.116: icmp_req=36 ttl=63 time=0.274 ms

64 bytes from 172.16.5.116: icmp_req=39 ttl=63 time=0.275 ms

64 bytes from 172.16.5.116: icmp_req=41 ttl=63 time=0.278 ms

64 bytes from 172.16.5.116: icmp_req=61 ttl=63 time=0.519 ms

64 bytes from 172.16.5.116: icmp_req=63 ttl=63 time=0.269 ms

64 bytes from 172.16.5.116: icmp_req=76 ttl=63 time=0.264 ms

64 bytes from 172.16.5.116: icmp_req=83 ttl=63 time=0.273 ms

--- 172.16.5.116 ping statistics ---

86 packets transmitted, 11 received, 87% packet loss, time 85150ms

rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.264/0.312/0.519/0.084 ms

What could be the reason for this?

Comment: I think that Superuser is not the right place to evaluate reasons for packet loss.... Likely this is a specific problem with your network...

Comment: It can be your router.

Comment: "some packet loss" is certainly an understatement. On a properly working network it should be far below 1%.